# How do I create visualization on AWS OpenSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch-dashboards

So I've added a few documents to AWS OpenSearch and indexed them.
When I go to the visualization --> Create new visualization --> I choose Gauge visualization --> Choose my index as source.

All I see at that point is a document count and I am unable to choose any values from within any of the documents. I am however, able to filter according to different fields within the document but not to actually present these fields. In Kibana once you choose a source, you are able to choose fields from within this source but I cant find this option on OpenSearch.

As you can see, I can see the "average" field but I cant choose to visualize it. The "Count 6" is
the number of documents I've indexed.

[image]

Comment: Have you defined a time field in your index pattern?

Comment: You were right, I was missing the time field - thanks.